# fabric 'failed' not working

Tags: python, fabric

I'd like to do something as simple as check if a string can be found in a file, and if not then do something. Fabric exits with an error. What work around is there?

```
result = local("grep %s /tmp/file" % env.hosts[0])
if result.failed:
    print "shit failed"
else:
    print "was already added, noop!"
```

Outputs

```
# fab -H 1.2.3.5
[localhost] local: grep 1.2.3.5 /etc/bitrate/puppetmaster/firewall

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'grep 1.2.3.5      /etc/bitrate/puppetmaster/firewall'

Aborting.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is 'with quiet():'

```
with quiet():
    result = local("something")
        if result.failed:
            ....
        else:
            ....
```